# Select all checkboxes and deselect them

Tags: javascript

I use this code to select all or deselect rows into table:

```
const selectAll = event => {
    let x = [];
    const checked = event.target.checked;
    const cbs: NodeListOf<HTMLInputElement> = document.querySelectorAll('.liquidationSpreadCb');
    cbs.forEach((cb: HTMLInputElement, i) => {
      cb.click();
      const itemId = cb.className.replace(/\D/g, '');
      const item: ILiquidationSpread = liquidationSpreadList.filter(val => val.id === Number(itemId))[0];
      x.push(item);
    });
    if (!checked) {
      x = [];
    }
    setSelectedItems(x);
  };
```

When I call this code using main select all checkout it's working fine. All table rows are selected.

But when I run the code and all rows are selected and after that I deselect for example 3-4 rows when I run the Java script code again the one selected become deselected.

In other words this JavaScript code changes selected to deselected and vice versa. It should select or deselect all checkboxes.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: please generate minimal reproduction of issue.

Answer (score 1):

This here logic can be used for selecting and deselecting checkboxes in a form.

```js
const form_change = e => {
  let form = e.target.form;
  // form.item could either be a NodeList or just one Element. A iterable is needed.
  let items = (form.item.length) ? form.item : [form.item];
  // switch on input name
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case 'selectall':
      // select all or none based on "selectall"
      let checked = e.target.checked;
      [...items].forEach(item => item.checked = checked);
      break;
    case 'item':
      // figure out if some "item" are checked
      let allchecked = ([...items].filter(item => !item.checked).length == 0) ?? true;
      // change "selectall" based on the result
      form.selectall.checked = allchecked ? true : false;
      break;
  }
};

document.forms.form01.addEventListener('change', form_change);
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th><input type="checkbox" name="selectall" /></th>
        <th>Items</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="1" /></td>
        <td>Item 1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="2" /></td>
        <td>Item 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="3" /></td>
        <td>Item 3</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, this functionality I need. Can you show me how this code can be edited so that I can use it like mine?

Comment: @user1285928 not really... Just use the same logic as I do and alter your own code.